# Падение приложения при проверки XML (проверка при загрузке) по схеме

Tags: xml, xsd

Столкнулся с падением приложения при проверки XML по схеме во время загрузки.

Методом научного тыка, было выяснено, что падение происходит из-за нуловой ссылки по XPATH.

Фрагмент проверки в XSD выглядит так:

```
 <xs:key name="icon_name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath="ws:icons/*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"></xs:field>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="small_icon_name_refer" refer="r:icon_name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//."></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@small_icon"></xs:field>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="large_icon_name_refer" refer="r:icon_name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//."></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@large_icon"></xs:field>
        </xs:keyref>
```

Сам по себе XML примерно выглядит так:

```
<template>
    <icons>
        <icon name='icon1'></icon>
        <icon name='icon2'></icon>
        <icon name='icon3'></icon>
        <icon name='icon4'></icon>
    </icons>
    <categories>
        <cagegory>
            <panel>
                <button small_icon='icon1'></button>
                <button large_icon='icon2'>
                    <button small_icon='icon3'>
                        <button small_icon='icon4'></button>
                    </button>
                    <label small_icon='icon1'></label>
                </button>
                <label small_icon='icon1'></label>
            </panel>
        </category>
    </categories>
</template>
```

Как я понял, падение происходит из-за того, что не у всех элементов может присутствовать один из атрибутов small_icon или large_icon.

Собственно вопрос, если это ошибка у microsoft при проверки xml при помощи схемы через msxml6, то как можно обойти данную ситуацию?

Суть задачи: проверить при наличии атрибута у элементов в `<category>` @small_icon или @large_icon наличие его в `<icons>\<icon[@name]>`

PS: Visual Studio 2013 прекрасно обрабатывает данную проверку внутри своего дизайнера/редактора

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка все же в xpath правильный селектор должен быть таким:

```
  <xs:keyref name="small_icon_name_refer" refer="r:icon_name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@small_icon"></xs:field>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="large_icon_name_refer" refer="r:icon_name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@large_icon"></xs:field>
        </xs:keyref>
```